# version 1 to version 5 in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to convert the below pined script from version 1 to version 5. I got stuck in the highlighted step. I need this code in version 5 because I have to merge this code with my another version 5 code. Could anyone please help me to convert the below code to version 5. Thanks

````
Factor=input(3, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(7, minval=1,maxval = 100)


Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))


//Need help in the below part
**TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown**

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red

plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "SuperTrend")

plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)

plotarrow(Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
plotarrow(Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)```
````

Answer (score 1):

The change you need to know is explained [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_version_3_migration_guide.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed).

Basically, you need to declare the variable first.

```
//Need help in the below part
TrendUp = 0.0
TrendUp := close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up

TrendDown = 0.0
TrendDown := close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = 0
Trend := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown
```

Comment: Hi @vitruvirus, Thank u so much for the answer. The solution is working well as expected.

Comment: Then please consider accepting my answer as an answer so we would know this problem is solved.

Comment: Hi @vitruvirus, I am unable to accept your answer..It looks like I need 15 reputation to accept your answer